# 2D scalar field: draw iso surface (iso line) with opacity

Tags: matplotlib, data-visualization, mayavi

I have two scalar fields on a 2D grid. I would like to draw a iso-line for the first scalar field an set its opacity according to the second scalar field.

I tried with mayavi starting from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15766555) but I couldn't switch from 3D to 2D.

Here's how I draw a iso line in mayavi (python).

```
 import numpy
 from mayavi import mlab

 x, y, z = numpy.ogrid[-5:5:64j, -5:5:64j, 0:0:1j]

 grid_x, grid_y, grid_z = numpy.mgrid[-5:5:64j, -5:5:64j, 0:0:1j]

 scalars = x*x*0.5 + y*y
 opacity = x**2
 opacity /= numpy.max(opacity) #normalize

 src = mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(grid_x,grid_y,grid_z, scalars)
 obj = mlab.pipeline.iso_surface(src, contours=[1,2,4,8,16,25,37],line_width=3)
 mlab.show()
```

I don't care about how the iso lines are obtained: any scientific data visualization tool and programming language is fine. The only thing I need is being able to set the opacity of the line.

Thanks

Comment: This is would be very difficult to do in mayavi.  What I intended to do was reproduce the colors precisely and then set them as a vtkUnsignedCharArray in the vtk source, but this did not work for this particular type of source.  I might look into this again later because I may end up working on making mayavi handle complex color information more flexibly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the global opacity of the line using

```
obj.actor.property.opacity = opacity
```

but opacity must be a scalar, you can't use a vector becasuse opacity is a global property of the actor